# Using Google Maps API to calculate distance between two addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

Context: I can't disclose too much about the project since I'm under NDA.

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.nmcmahon.co.uk/using-the-google-maps-directions-api-to-calculate-distances/) to calculate the distance between two addresses using Google Maps.

I am looking to output the distance between the origin address, which is a fixed point, and the destination address, which is dependent on what the user inputs in the `_ct_text_53ea3270e6e6d` field.

It works fine pulling from one address, but if it pulls from multiple maps, it only shows the distance from one of the maps, not from each of them.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$field_value = do_shortcode('[ct id="_ct_text_53ea3270e6e6d" property="title | description | value"]'); 

// Our parameters
$params = array(
    'origin'        => '900 South Crouse Ave, Syracuse, NY, 13210',
    'destination'   => $field_value,
    'sensor'        => 'true',
    'units'         => 'imperial'
);

// Join parameters into URL string
foreach($params as $var => $val){
    $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);  
}

// Request URL
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".ltrim($params_string, '&');

// Make our API request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Parse the JSON response
$directions = json_decode($return);

// Print distance
 print('<p><strong>Distance from Campus: </strong>' .$directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text. '</p>');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple maps"? And what is "problems"? Looks like you're only showing one map in your code. . . . Hint: [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is much nicer than `print` to output HTML strings.

Comment: @brasofilo Sorry for the confusion. I'm under NDA not to disclose too much about the project, but I have updated my original question.

Comment: But how to reproduce the problem? I just tried with a simple PHP file (no WP), converted your code to a function, called it 2 times and it worked ok. Check the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @brasofilo I think it has to do with the input field within $field_value. I'm using [CustomPress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/custompress/) to create a custom field so the PHP code above pulls from that input. What other pieces of code should I add to help others understand my problem?

Comment: This is what I tried:http://pastebin.com/yrPJTZws - Put the exact returned values from your `$field_value` to test

Comment: @brasofilo Your code does work for when I manually put in the addresses, but when trying to pull from the input field, it gets rid of the maps and only shows up once. [Here is what I'm seeing](http://imgur.com/mAY5yV5). This code is acting very strange imo.

Comment: Are you saying that this exact code, if built as a Shortcode, doesn't work? Did you check the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide?

Comment: @brasofilo I apologize for all this frustration and I appreciate the help you are giving me. PHP is somewhat foreign to me, so I always have trouble with it. [Here is what I used](http://pastebin.com/6DJwUdnf). It's your exact code, with the origin address changed and the shortcode in the do_it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Using an independent PHP file won't allow the use of WordPress functions (`do_shortcode()`). I think the main issue may be the result of this shortcode. If you grab 2 values generated by the shortcode (eg, "Address 1, City, ZIP") and feed into the independent PHP file (running `do_it()` 2x), does it work?

Comment: Yep. It worked feeding in the address manually. However, I do need this shortcode to be used to get the addresses or it will defeat the purpose of the code.

Comment: So, the problem is that the shortcode is not working..? Does `$field_value` contain a valid address?

Comment: All addresses entered are valid because it is generating a google map from that field. I believe the code can't recognize more than one address and only gets the distance of one value.

Comment: Well, if you read the MCVE guide I've already mentioned twice and produce an example where I can reproduce the problem, I can give it a go... Otherwise, I don't know how to further help...

Comment: I'm sorry for being frustrating. I'm not sure how to reproduce the problem since the code requires a lot of Wordpress integration. If you want to see the problem in action, you can [visit this site](http://orgs-dev.syr.edu/cc-test/), select Clinic or Agency, Female, and Mood/Anxiety as the search terms. It will take you to the search results page that show the problem. [Here is a link](http://pastebin.com/2YZQ1JSN) to the results page loop code. If you click into one of the results, the code works fine since it draws from one field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to replace this:

```
// Join parameters into URL string
foreach($params as $var => $val){
    $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);
}
```

With:

```
$params_string = http_build_query($params);
```